# Jodatime LenientChronology parser double counting

Tags: parsing, jodatime

The following Scala code returns 121,000ms instead of the expected 61,000ms. This applies to other fields (e.g. hour of day) as well, and seems to be caused by double-counting the out-of-range value twice. The documentation and tests for LenientChronology don't seem to throw any light on this behaviour, so was wondering if anyone know of or could provide an explaination for this behaviour.

```
import org.joda.time.chrono.{ISOChronology, LenientChronology}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder

val secondNumber = "61"

val lenientChronology = LenientChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC)

val lenientParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendSecondOfMinute(1).toFormatter.withChronology(lenientChronology)

lenientParser.parseMillis(secondNumber)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I suggest you to file an issue on Joda-issue-tracker since that project is still in maintenance mode (no enhancements but continued bugfixing).

Comment: @MenoHochschild I've raised https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/432

Answer (score 0):

We can also use PeriodFormatterBuilder instead:

import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder

`val hoursMinutes =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendLiteral(":").appendMinutes().appendLiteral(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter
val duration = hoursMinutes.parsePeriod("40:50:23").toStandardDuration
duration.getMillis`

It handles LenientChronology on the fly